# Slow - Open and close connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, ado.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on Windows Azure with SQL Azure. The application uses SqlClient to connect to the database. I'm always using the same connectionString (To use connection pool):

```
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Static Connection String"))
        {
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {                    
                conn.Open();
                return command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

I noticed that there is a considerable time between the opening of the connections that leaving the slow implementation. For example, if I have a page with four selectlist, the application needs to open the connection four times to fill the lists. If you do this with one command, returning all lists, the performance is incredible, but when I open and close the connection to get the result lists separately the performance falls too.

With a windows forms application that does not happen.

**My doubt is, is there any limitation to the environment in which I am running?**

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't keep the connection opened? Also, sometimes running an application in Debug mode can be significantly slower than in Release, which has optimizations

Comment: @PhilippeParé keeping the connection open will only create significant problems. ADO.NET uses connection pooling so it *doesn't* have to open new connections. Instead, it reuses connections that were previously closed.

Comment: The problem is that you execute 4 queries, not that you open 4 connections - you don't. Connection pooling means that you reuse the same connection. You still have to *send* a request to the server though, wait and retrieve the answer. It's the 4 roundtrips that kill performance. 4 queries will be up to 4 times slower than a single query, no matter what. If the data retrieved is small, the roundtrip overhead is way more expensive than the query itself

Comment: One answer is to batch queries. An even better answer is to use caching for lookup data so that you *don't* have to retrieve the same selections all the time. Add to that output caching to avoid rendering the same page if the parameters don't change

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, please, post your comment as answer that i will mark it as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you execute 4 queries, not that you open 4 connections - you don't. Connection pooling means that you reuse the same connection.

You still have to send a request to the server though, wait and retrieve the answer. It's the 4 roundtrips that kill performance. 4 queries will be up to 4 times slower than a single query, no matter what. If the data retrieved is small, the roundtrip overhead is way more expensive than the query itself.

You should try to reduce database calls or eliminate them altogether:

- Use batching to combine multiple queries into a single call.
- Use caching for lookup data so that you don't have to retrieve the same selections all the time.
- Finally, use output caching to avoid rendering the same page if the request parameters don't change.